# JQUERY add class if has class myclassN where N is greater than X alternate width

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code:

```
<style>
.div66{width: 66.6%}
.div33{width: 33.3%}
</style>

<div class="box1">content</div>
<div class="box2">content</div>
<div class="box3">content</div>
<div class="box4">content</div>
<div class="box5">content</div>
<div class="box6">content</div>
<div class="box7">content</div>
<div class="box8">content</div>
<div class="box9">content</div>
<div class="box10">content</div>
```

I need to obtain below with a jQuery function.

```
<style>
.div66{width: 66.6%}
.div33{width: 33.3%}
</style>

<div class="box1">content</div>
<div class="box2">content</div>
<div class="box3 div66">content</div>
<div class="box4 div33">content</div>
<div class="box5 div33">content</div>
<div class="box6 div66">content</div>
<div class="box7 div66">content</div>
<div class="box8 div33">content</div>
<div class="box9 div33">content</div>
<div class="box10 div66">content</div>
```

If boxN is greatest than 3 apply divXX class, and after first div66 toggles 2x div33 and 2x div66

**UPDATE**

I solved using CSS and nth-child

```
<style>
.box:nth-child(n+3) {width: 33.3%}
.box:nth-child(4n+3), .box:nth-child(4n+6) {width: 66.6%}
</style>

<div class="box box1">content</div>
<div class="box box2">content</div>
<div class="box box3">content</div>
<div class="box box4">content</div>
<div class="box box5">content</div>
<div class="box box6">content</div>
<div class="box box7">content</div>
<div class="box box8">content</div>
<div class="box box9">content</div>
<div class="box box10">content</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I would have done so:
`var boxclass = $('div').class();
var boxnumber = boxclass.substring(3);
if(boxnumber > 2) {
  $(boxclass).addClass('div66');
}`
but I do not know how to toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by,

```
var elems = $("div").filter(":nth-child(3)").addClass("div66").nextAll().get(),isThree = true;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 2) {
  $(elems[i]).add(elems[i + 1]).addClass(isThree ? "div33" : "div66");
  isThree = !isThree;
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/28vzLvss/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 1, prev = 66;
  $('[class^="box"]').each(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);
    alert(num);
    if(num >= 3) {
      if(i == 0) {
        if(prev == 33) {
          $(this).addClass('div66');
          prev = 66;
          
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('div33');
          prev = 33;
          
        }
        i++;
      } else {
        i++;
        i = i%2;
        if(prev == 66) {
          $(this).addClass('div66');
          prev = 66;
          
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('div33');
          prev = 33;
           
        }
 
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.div66{width: 66.6%; color: green;}
.div33{width: 33.3%; color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">content</div>
<div class="box2">content</div>
<div class="box3">content</div>
<div class="box4">content</div>
<div class="box5">content</div>
<div class="box6">content</div>
<div class="box7">content</div>
<div class="box8">content</div>
<div class="box9">content</div>
<div class="box10">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try playing on selectors

```js
$('div[class^=box]:gt(2)')
  .filter(':nth-child(4n+1), :nth-child(4n+2)')
  .addClass('div33');

$('div[class^=box]:gt(1)')
  .not('.div33')
  .addClass('div66');
```

```css
.div66 {
  width: 66.6%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.div33 {
  width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">content</div>
<div class="box2">content</div>
<div class="box3">content</div>
<div class="box4">content</div>
<div class="box5">content</div>
<div class="box6">content</div>
<div class="box7">content</div>
<div class="box8">content</div>
<div class="box9">content</div>
<div class="box10">content</div>
```